# How to resolve a "define is not defined" error when using jasmine karma with compiled typescript to test a component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a typescript app that has been compiled down to a single file, myjs.js in the js folder. And I have karma jasmine setup on my workspace.

in the myjs.js there is the code

```
var require, define, requirejs;
(function() {compiled typescript code here } )();
etc etc etc;
```

Somewhere inside my compiled typescript is the code

```
define('component/to/test', ["dependencies"], function(dependencies){ ... }
```

in my jasmine testscript, I have,

```
define([component/to/test], function(component){ jasmine specifications here} );
```

However, when running the jasmine file with karma start, I get the error that

```
define is not defined
```

I checked the karma config file, both files are included as js/*.js and spec/*.js .

Any idea what I am doing wrong, this is the first time doing something like this.

Comment: You need to use an AMD compliant loader.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: By using an AMD loader like RequireJS or the Dojo loader. You can also load AMD modules with SystemJS.

Comment: I have requirejs and karma-requirejs modules and added them to the files in karma config. But when running the karma start, its never karma is executing but nothing changes. I am not getting any tests back.

Comment: running karma run in a different command prompt after doing it in the command line causes it to say the browsers are not ready, and its been at it for a about 10 minutes now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
I forgot to do karma run after karma start.